# Using Keras NN to predict risk

Tags: keras, risk

#### Question

What is the best `activation` to use for a keras NN predicting risk of a single binary outcome? Is it [sigmoid](https://keras.io/activations/#sigmoid)? And are there some approaches I can use to get better predictions on the low-frequency risks?

#### Background

I have about 400K records of surgical procedures and multiple post-procedure adverse outcomes. I will train separate models for each outcome.

The risk of these outcomes varies from ~1:10000 to ~2:10. (I recognise I may need to group some of the rare outcomes together)

I'm hoping to use a keras to produce a predicted risk based on various factors (such as patient age, medical conditions, class of surgery, etc etc). I can then use the predicted and actual rates in various populations (eg patients treated by particular doctor) to look for patterns of variation.

I have this example [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tutorial-first-neural-network-python-keras/), as well as [this paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5510858/) ([model](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/BeaconLabs/readmission-risk/master/model/model_100.json)) both of which use the sigmoid activation.

(As an aside, the situation is similar to the [ACS NSQIP Surgical Risk Calculator](https://riskcalculator.facs.org/RiskCalculator/) but the my goals and data vary from this tool.)